# Difference in array composing

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to build an array and while doing so, I was wondering if it makes any difference in how you create such array. Things I have in mind are performance, maintainability, readability,...

Declaration 1:

```
$data = array(
    'my_array' => array(
    'table' => array(
       'group' => t('My group'),
       'join'  => array(
          'commerce_product' => array(
             'left_field'  => 'sku',
             'field'       => 'artc',
           ),
        ),
     );
```

Declaration 2:

```
$data['my_array']['table']['group'] = 'My group';
$data['my_array']['table']['join']['commerce_product'] = array(
    'left_field'  => 'sku',
    'field'       => 'artc',);
```

Because for some reason, my Drupal site accepts the first declaration but not the second. Since it's about creating arrays in PHP I don't think it has something to do with Drupal, rather with the way the array is created...

Comment: Using PHP 5.4+, you can also do `$data = ['my_array' = ['table' => 'foo']]` , etc.

Comment: PS: We'd need to see more code to see what's going on. It doesn't matter how you create the array, but how it's used.

Answer (score 0):

The feature of automatically creating an array with the second syntax (assigning a value to a key in a non-existent variable) is a more recent feature than using the `array` syntax.

Check the PHP version installed on your two servers.